# Using list to sum a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, sum

Consider the following dataframe in R:

```
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(10,20,30))
```

Consider I want to sum the value for "Agriculture" and "Fishery" (10 + 20 = 30). For example, I could do it like this:

```
df$Value[df$Industry == "Agriculture"] + df$Value[df$Industry == "Fishery"]
```

However, instead I want to create list with "Agriculture" and "Fishery", and thereafter summing the value. Because in my example I have a big data.frame, and that will make it a lot easier. How to do that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "create list with agriculture and fishery ... summing the value".
Can you share the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `%in%`:

```
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(10, 20, 30))
print(df)
industries_to_sum <- c("Agriculture", "Fishery")
print(sum(df[df$Industry %in% industries_to_sum,]$Value))
```

**Output:**

```
     Industry Value
1 Agriculture    10
2     Fishery    20
3    Industry    30
[1] 30
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, a tidyverse approach:

```
df <- data.frame(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(10, 20, 30))
df %>% filter(Industry %in% c("Agriculture", "Fishery")) %>%
    summarise(sumValue=sum(Value))
```

Output:

```
  sumValue
1       30
```

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table()` approach

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Industry = c("Agriculture", "Fishery", "Industry"),
                 Value    = c(10,20,30))

DT[Industry != "Industry"][, sum(Value)]
```

Output

```
> [1] 30
```